# Trouble using git with TextMate

Tags: git, textmate

I am trying to use git with TextMate. When I want to initialize a repo, I have this message error, even if I pointed the TM_GIT shell variable to the right 'which git' :

/Applications/TextMate.app/Contents/SharedSupport/Bundles/Git.tmbundle/Support/tmvc/../lib/git.rb:382:in `chdir': can't convert nil into String (TypeError) from /Applications/TextMate.app/Contents/SharedSupport/Bundles/Git.tmbundle/Support/tmvc/../lib/git.rb:382:in`init' from....

Does anybody has an idea ?

By the way, is it possible to integrate the terminal in the TextMate environment like Aptana IDE does ?

Best,
Mehdi

Answer (score 1):

I can't answer on the first (and most important) part of your question but the answer to the second part is no. You can run external commands and even get nice clickable output but there's no way to integrate a terminal emulator into TextMate. Maybe in 2.0?